# Problem to create a bibtex file to be used in LATEX

Tags: bibtex

Here is the content of the Bibtex that I want to use as bibliography for LATEX file (paper):

```
@article{kargupta2004fourier,
      title={A fourier spectrum-based approach to represent decision trees for mining data streams in mobile environments},
      author={Kargupta, Hillol and Park, Byung-Hoon},
      journal={Knowledge and Data Engineering, IEEE Transactions on},
      volume={16},
      number={2},
      pages={216--229},
      year={2004},
      publisher={IEEE}
    }

@article{mukherjee2006privacy,
  title={A privacy-preserving technique for Euclidean distance-based mining algorithms using Fourier-related transforms},
  author={Mukherjee, Shibnath and Chen, Zhiyuan and Gangopadhyay, Aryya},
  journal={The VLDB Journal—The International Journal on Very Large Data Bases},
  volume={15},
  number={4},
  pages={293--315},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Springer-Verlag New York, Inc.}
}
```

I would to save the file with name BIB1. However, I have option to save it in TexStudio as txt file or as a TEXfile (list of extensions includes *.tex, *.bib). 
How to save it? and afterwards should I compile it or use the command Bibtex?

Comment: save the file as .bib, but This is an exact duplicate of your question of a few minutes ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save it with .bib and compile with latex-bibtex-latex-latex and then take a look at the pdf.

Take a look also to the other quesetion. If you need help take a look at these gifs I just made.

Create the bib file

[image: bib]

Compile with latex-bibtex-latex-latex

[image]

All files can be downloaded here: [Google drive link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4HppN1nEJ6KeGVsc0RaTEE1Unc&usp=sharing)

Comment: When I save it (the file name is try17) I get the following error message:Process started: bibtex.exe "try17"

I couldn't open file name `try17.aux'

Process exited normally

Comment: Hmm... have you tried creating the .bib file with a normal text editor, like notepad++?

Comment: Yes, But there is no option to save it as .bib.

Comment: You can just save it and afterwards change the file kind.

Comment: I tried the regular notepad and created a new file with the .bib extension. The file type now is BibTex Database I hope this is OK?

Comment: That's fine. Take a look at my edited answer if something is unclear.

Comment: Thank you so much. My problem was that I didn't save the source file as .tex. Now I see the bibliography and one article is missing. I'll be glad if you can see my next question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288494/missing-of-bibliography-and-order-as-is/288499#288499