# Missing of Bibliography and order as-is

Tags: bibtex

Here is my tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}

 \begin{document}
 \nocite{*}
 \begin{abstract}
 zzz
 \end{abstract}
 \section{Introduction}
 zzzz

 \bibliography{BibliographyforpaperFull}
 \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

 \end{document}
```

And here is my bib file (BibliographyforpaperFull.bib). One citation is missing. 
In addition, I would like to get the order as-is in the current bib file with numbers per article like [1], [2] for each article. And to use it in the body of the paper as number.

```
  @article{kargupta2004fourier,
      title={A fourier spectrum-based approach to represent decision trees for mining data streams in mobile environments},
      author={Kargupta, Hillol and Park, Byung-Hoon},
      journal={Knowledge and Data Engineering, IEEE Transactions on},
      volume={16},
      number={2},
      pages={216--229},
      year={2004},
      publisher={IEEE}
    }

    @article{mukherjee2006privacy,
      title={A privacy-preserving technique for Euclidean distance-based mining algorithms using Fourier-related transforms},
      author={Mukherjee, Shibnath and Chen, Zhiyuan and Gangopadhyay, Aryya},
      journal={The VLDB Journal—The International Journal on Very Large Data Bases},
      volume={15},
      number={4},
      pages={293--315},
      year={2006},
      publisher={Springer-Verlag New York, Inc.}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get 36 bibliography entries when I compile your example under the `unsrt` style - that prints numbers [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dinMa.png), [2], ...:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\bibliography{BibliographyforpaperFull}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\end{document}
```

In order to use a citation in your document, use `\cite{<bibkey>}`, where `<bibkey>` is the part in your `.bib` file used as

```
@<type>{<bibkey>, <key-value fields}
```

Two BibTeX *warnings* were issued:

- `gehrke1999boat`: "Can't use both `volume` and `number` fields;
- `hansen1990neural`: "There's a `number` but no `volume`.

Comment: Thank you very much. But there are 37 bibliography entries, that's my problem.... In addition, I would like to see the bibliography in the order as seen in my source bib file

Comment: @Avi Maybe you should have scaled down the problem to just two entries to make it more obvious ;-)

Comment: After getting an answer for one question I'll open for the next one.

Comment: @Avi: You only supplied 36 entries from what I can count... And, the bibliography appears in the order they are given in the `.bib` (and therefore `uns`o`rt`ed).